# Overlaying bargraph in kibana visulization

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I have document which I am uploading into elastic using python which have data as below

```
{'PN': 'P', 'BuildNumber': 1235, 'component': 'ps', 'applicationDetails': {'application': 'Adobe Reader DC', 'filename': 'ACDCPREP_ISO_PGS1'}, 'timestamp': {'startUnixTime': 0.0, 'endUnixTime': 11.369999885559082, 'jobStart': 2.6649789810180664, 'jobEnd': 2.6688709259033203}}
```

I will be continuously streaming data into ELK , which different build number.
I want to plot the bar graph in which I want `x-axis` with `BuildNumber` and `y-axis` will contain the time from startUnixTime to endUnixTime , on the same bar i want to see overlay where it need to start from jobStart-->2.6649 and end at jobEnd--> 2.6688

I am NOT able to overlay